# PHP change the maximum upload file size in php

Tags: php

I want to upload 20 MB file in php, but file is not uploading.

i have changed the php.ini file but still file is not uploading.

Changes of php.ini file is below.

```
max_execution_time = 300 
upload_max_filesize = 64M 
post_max_size = 64M
```

any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: did you restart your server after modifying php.ini?

Comment: are you using any FastCGI or something?

Answer (score 1):

You have made the necessary changes in the `php.ini` file, however after doing the changes in your `php.ini` file you need to **restart** your HTTP server to use new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need a restart Apache  web server after changed in configuration of Apache file.
Restart Apache web server, enter:

```
 # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you are using Ubuntu use sudo:

```
  $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```